# How to tweet with the app name, not on behalf of the owner of the app/developer

Tags: twitter

I'm using Twitter API for my website in PHP.
I have created a developer account `"me"` let's say.
I have then created an app named `"myapp"`. I've generated tokens and keys with Read&Write permissions.

My problem : when I tweet via my website (using the API) and using my app tokens and keys, my tweets appear in https://twitter.com/me as if `"me"` were the author of the tweet, and the app name does not appear anywhere...
How could I tweet with my app name as the author ?

To be more clear,  I would like to see the tweets posted (via the API using the tokens and keys of `"myapp"`) in https://twitter.com/myapp and with `"myapp"` as the author of the tweet.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When you say "on behalf of", could you clarify? What do you expect and what exactly happens? For example, do you mean that you see "me" as the _author_ of the tweet and you expect "myapp" as the author? Perhaps post a screenshot of the result with a highlight of what you see as wrong behavior.

Comment: I edited my question and hope I've clarified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, your app posts on behalf of an account that has granted permissions, so what you're seeing is "working as expected" from the outside. In order to have your app be an author, create an account specifically for it to tweet to.

The app technically still won't be the author, your dedicated account is, but you would (probably) set up that dedicated account to represent your app (URL if it's public, icon/photo, etc).

Note that you'll use the auth keys you get when attaching the app to the custom account instead of the ones that you're currently using for attaching it to your developer account.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.  I don't understand the use of Twiiter apps. Why can we have many apps  if the only author possible is the owner ?

Comment: It's not the owner, as such. Tweets come from accounts. Apps are authorized to perform actions (like tweet) for an account. Hence, your app has to be attached to an account to tweet. Your app could in theory be attached to many accounts and tweet as each of them.